# "XDomainRequest" не определено

Tags: javascript

Выполняю запрос

```
    var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
    xdr.open("get", "http://iamilya.ru/images/ILItv/RU/1_RU.html");
    xdr.send();
    var text_get = xdr.responseText;
```

Вылетает ошибка

```
 Ошибка выполнения JavaScript: "XDomainRequest" не определено
```

Comment: IE8+ и только

Comment: Использую в приложении магазин WINDOWS

Comment: Других вариантов где разрешены http нету

Comment: Тогда вам [WinJS.xhr][1] нужен, не?
[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx

Comment: Ошибка выполнения JavaScript: "WinJS" не определено